# Android: Rendering RadioButton as an ordinary Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Is there a way to create a RadioGroup consisting of a few RadioButtons, such that the look of each RadioButton is like an ordinary Button rather than the default look (a checked circle beside some text)?

Is it necessary to fall back on a LinearLayout of Buttons and manually change the background of the buttons when handling button presses in a listener?

**Edit**: To be concrete, say we have two RadioButtons, foo and bar. When one is pressed, the string is displayed in boldface. The small circles that are normally next to each RadioButton is omitted. Is it necessary to manually make the change from and to boldface?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put a custom look for you radio buttons, such as adding android:background=@drawable... and then setting a custom image for checked and unchecked state.